# Yii2 query with comparison value

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to find all trucks with certain statuses

So this is the way am doing it

```
$trucks::TblTrucks::find()
         ->where(["!=" "status", 13])
          ->andWhere(["!=" "status", 14])
          ->andWhere(["!=" "status", 17])
          ->andWhere(["!=" "status", 2])
```

The above works but looks abiit messed up so i wanted to rewrite it to

```
$trucks::TblTrucks::find()
         ->where(["!=" "status", [13,14, 17,2])
```

But the above fails.
Where am i going wrong? or how can i rewrite it including all status values in an array.

Comment: Fails how? Do you get an error? I see missing commas, is this it?

Answer (score 2):

```
"!="
```

does not work with array in Yii2 and in MySql
and you missed the comma after that

Try:

```
->where(["NOT IN", "status", [13,14,17,2])
```

[More details in the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail)